How to get the list of widgets that are visible in Flutter?
I am currently developing a component in a Flutter project, which requires the functionality of fetching the list of widgets that are currently visible in the screen, ideally with their attributes (e.g. background color) and current location (e.g. the x and y related to the screen), at the time its button is tapped. I did some research and the only relevant feature I found was https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector which can detect visibility change on a single widget.
Is there a way to detect all widgets rather than just one? I am not looking for a way to subscribe to visibility changes, but just get the list of all visible (and mounted) widgets on the current page.

cannot you use ListView.builder ?

@pskink Not just list view, I wish to get all widgets that are available and visible regardless if they are within a ListView or not. Ideally everything that is a child widget of the MaterialApp.

so all of them have to be children of SingleChildScrollView, if so, use ScrollController and check their visibility inside the listener
